# mod_wsgi for Django on Mac OSX 10.5.8

Tags: python, django, apache, deployment, mod-wsgi

I'm a newbie learning Django, and couldn't get the development server accessible externally. So I'm looking into other deployment options. It seems that mod_wsgi is the way to go (with Apache), but it only supports OSX 10.6+. Are there any alternatives if you own 10.5.8?

Comment: The development server should never be made accessible externally unless it's to demo a product for a minimal number of people, it is absolutely not secured for a production environment.  Prior to mod_wsgi the most common method of deploying a python site with apache was mod_python.  It's still around and should support 10.5.8

Answer (score 1):

Taking @Endophage's warning into consideration, if you still want to do this you probably need to start the server like this:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

By default, the dev server only listens on localhost so you need to explicitly tell it to listen on external interfaces. If you have a firewall or something like that disallowing traffic on that port and/or still want/need to use apache, you can bypass the need for mod_wsgi by setting up [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy.html) in your apache config to proxy all requests to that port. This should only be done for development though, you're asking for trouble if you deploy to production using the methods I just outlined.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem running mod_wsgi on OSX 10.5, a precompiled binary isn't supplied that is all. You would need to compile it from source code, meaning you would need to have XCode installed. Otherwise you wait a week until I get home and I will build a mod_wsgi.so for OSX 10.5 and I will put it up for download. Post to the mod_wsgi mailing list in about a week asking again about it.

Answer (score 0):

Gunicorn is the fastest way to having a production ready web server serving your site that I've found in the Django realm. It is a Python WSGI HTTP Server for UNIX.

Steps involved to deploy your site using gunicorn:

> > pip install gunicorn
> >
> > Add 'gunicorn' your installed apps listed in settings.py
> >
> > ./manage.py run_gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8001 --daemon